# retrieve from ADO.net and create webApi

Tags: c#, azure, serialization, asp.net-web-api

i'm trying to create a webapi that retrieve data from sqlserver on azure and i got this error.
i'm new in asp.net webapi this is my frist time i was watch a tutorial and i did what he was doing but i got this error

Stacktrace:

```
 at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext.SerializeAndVerifyType(DataContract dataContract, XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj, Boolean verifyKnownType, RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle, Type declaredType) 
at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext.SerializeWithXsiTypeAtTopLevel(DataContract dataContract, XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj, RuntimeTypeHandle originalDeclaredTypeHandle, Type graphType) 
at System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractSerializer.InternalWriteObjectContent(XmlWriterDelegator writer, Object graph, DataContractResolver dataContractResolver) 
at System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractSerializer.InternalWriteObject(XmlWriterDelegator writer, Object graph, DataContractResolver dataContractResolver) 
at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializer.WriteObjectHandleExceptions(XmlWriterDelegator writer, Object graph, DataContractResolver dataContractResolver) 
at System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractSerializer.WriteObject(XmlWriter writer, Object graph) 
at System.Net.Http.Formatting.XmlMediaTypeFormatter.WriteToStream(Type type, Object value, Stream writeStream, HttpContent content) 
at System.Net.Http.Formatting.XmlMediaTypeFormatter.WriteToStreamAsync(Type type, Object value, Stream writeStream, HttpContent content, TransportContext transportContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken) --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- 
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) 
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) 
at System.Web.Http.WebHost.HttpControllerHandler.<WriteBufferedResponseContentAsync>d__1b.MoveNext()
```

my controller

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web.Http;
using DataBaseAccess;
namespace JoSaleWebApi.Controllers
{
public class BrandController : ApiController
{
   public IEnumerable<brand_Table> Get()
    {
        using (JoSaleDbEntities enitites = new JoSaleDbEntities())
        {
            return enitites.brand_Table.ToList();
        }

    }
    public brand_Table Get(int id)
    {
        using (JoSaleDbEntities enitites = new JoSaleDbEntities())
        {
            return enitites.brand_Table.FirstOrDefault(b => b.brand_id == id);
        }
    }
}}
```

ADO generated class

```
namespace DataBaseAccess
{
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public partial class brand_Table
{
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public brand_Table()
    {
        this.branch_Table = new HashSet<branch_Table>();
        this.sale_Table = new HashSet<sale_Table>();
    }

    public int brand_id { get; set; }
    public string brand_name { get; set; }
    public string brand_imageUrl { get; set; }
    public int company_id { get; set; }

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<branch_Table> branch_Table { get; set; }
    public virtual company_Table company_Table { get; set; }
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<sale_Table> sale_Table { get; set; }
}
```

}

[image: webConfig]

Comment: What is the question? You have posted no code. Please clarify.

Comment: @Goose i added picture of controller code and entity classes

Comment: You need your code pasted in the question, not in an image.

Comment: @Goose i have added the code

Comment: This is not the whole error message? Could you please post the errormessage you got? Anyway is there any resson why you're using ado.net instead of entity framework?

Comment: The error you posted above is from the server or at the client? You need to debug the web API and try to get the exact exception. Also which line of code throws exception is also useful to know to provide the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your stack trace and code, I found that you didn't apply DataContract for your entity and didn't provide DataContractResolver for XmlFormatter. Another problem is that serializing an entity model(brand_Table) which has relation with other entity model(company_Table). This relationship causes self referencing loop exception while serialization the entity to JOSN or xml. To solve the issues, you could set LazyLoadingEnabled and ProxyCreationEnabled properties to false in the construction method of your database context.

```
public JoSaleDbEntities()
        : base("name=JoSaleDbEntities ")
{
    this.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
    this.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
}
```